# How do I incorporate a connection adapter and obtain items from a JSON payload using Python?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am attempting to use the requests module, in order to obtain items from a dictionary, which corresponds to the JSON payload of a Gsheet.

I attempt to do this via this function

```
def get_var(request, item):
    file_id = requests.get(request)[item]
    return file_id
```

The following error pops up, which I would expect not, since I'm feeding a json object and treating it as dictionary, which it is, right ?

```
raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}")
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "{'file_id': '1wNCvE-ZMBd0Ovy6p1JcK2YFkexdPAt2j51jDBVEVdn0', 'file_name': 'TEST file'}"
```

Comment: `requests.get` returns a `response` object.  What are you trying to fetch?

Comment: to get the response as a JSON you can use response.json()

Comment: fetching a value from the key:value pairs that the JSON object has @TimRoberts

Comment: `requests.get` does not return a JSON object.  It returns a `response` object.  Lucas has the answer.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: I think you may have two problems in this code and in this error message. First: you need `,json()` to get it as dictionary - `file_id = requests.get(request).json()[item]`. But I think current code should generate different error. Your error may suggest that you get `.content` and you used it as `url` in next `requests.get("{'file_id': '1wNCvE-ZMBd0Ovy6p1JcK2YFkexdPAt2j51jDBVEVdn0', 'file_name': 'TEST file'}")` which is wrong URL and this generates `InvalidSchema` because it doesn't have `https://` at the beginning of URL. Maybe you should use `print()` to see what you have in variables.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. @furas you are right, I should append the whole error stack. Turns out I am feeding a JSON payload directly, which is a dict, and in return I'm looking for a value to a certain key. So this simple code worked : ```file_id = request[item]```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

simply treating `request`, the input var, as the dictionary that it's expected to be, I was able to return the value from said dictionary's key, value pairs.

`file_id = request[item]` did the job.

There was no need for the `requests` module after all, since I am already feeding a dictionary into the function.